# Matching 2 Data.Map package versions

Tags: haskell

I import the package Data.Map like this: `import qualified Data.Map as M`, I have a variable with the type:

```
> :t particleMap 
particleMap :: M.Map PID (Particle (Float, Float))
```

Now, I want to pass my variable `particleMap` into a data with type as follow:

```
> :t Ensemble
Ensemble
  :: [([Edge], Point v -> Point v -> v)]
     -> containers-0.4.2.1:Data.Map.Map PID (Particle v) -> Ensemble v
```

Please have a look at the 2nd argument. It is `containers-0.4.2.1:Data.Map.Map PID (Particle v)`, not like `Data.Map.Map`, or not like `M.Map`. Finally, it causes the error like this:

```
Couldn't match expected type `containers-0.4.2.1:Data.Map.Map
                                    PID (Particle (Float, Float))'
                with actual type `M.Map PID (Particle (Float, Float))'
```

I double-check the version of the package containers, I noticed I have installed 2 versions:

> Versions installed: 0.4.2.1, 0.5.1.0

So, I guess, the computer is confused with 2 versions, that's why leads to the error. Is it?

Comment: Yes, that's what leads to the error, you've got that right. The real question would be why GHC loads to different versions of the package simultaneously. This shouldn't ever happen if you properly [cabalise](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/) your project.

Comment: I am wonder if we can import exactly the version of the package containers-0.4.2.1 without handling with cabal. For example, `import qualified containers-0.4.2.1:Data.Map as M`

Comment: I unregistered the version of the containers 0.5.1.0, and was so lucky that no package dependencies was affected. And compiling is ok. But any other suggestion is welcome. Thanks

Comment: You can use the GHC (and GHCi) flag `-package containers-0.4.2.1` to use the earlier version without needing to uninstall the newer. This should not cause any problems unless you use functions that expose Data.Map.Map (not just using it internally) and were compiled against a different version of containers, and you should be able to use the OPTIONS_GHC pragma to specify this in the source file.

Answer (score 1):

GHC will typically assume that an import should draw from the latest version of all packages that are available. Likely something pulled in the new version of containers as a dependency. The correct thing to do, which you did, was to just unregister it. Had you not wanted to do so, you could have just used `ghc-pkg hide` to keep ghc from using it by default.

In any case, the typical next step would be to find the culprit package that forced you to pull a new containers, and modify its cabal to use the older one.

This is because containers is a package very far down the dependency chain, and updating it typically forces you to "rebuild the world" to get everything else to use the newer version, which is often quite difficult.